# Filter ListView data

Tags: android, listview, search

I am working on an App where data is read from XML, then based on the data, It creates an ListView and clicking on any item in ListView it opens another activity with details. I am trying to implement search functionality in the ListView, below is my code, I don't know how ti implement Search, I tried many ways but none of them worked. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class BrowseActors extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "QuizListActivity";
    private ImageView bannerImageView; // displays a Image
    // Search EditText
    private EditText inputSearch;
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_TAG = "ActorData"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_ICON = "icon";

    String position;
    String sourceFile;
    // List items
    ListView list;
    //BinderActorData adapter = null;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> actorDataCollection;
    ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Remove title
        setContentView(R.layout.browse_actor);
        bannerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.topImageView);
        try {
            // Get Category to filter
            Intent in = getIntent();
            this.position = in.getStringExtra("position");
            sourceFile="BaseData.xml"
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(getAssets().open(sourceFile));

            actorDataCollection = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList quizList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ActorData");

            HashMap<String, String> map = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < quizList.getLength(); i++) {

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                Node firstQuestionNode = quizList.item(i);

                if (firstQuestionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element firstAircraftElement = (Element) firstQuestionNode;
                        // 1.-------
                        NodeList idList = firstAircraftElement
                                .getElementsByTagName(KEY_ID);
                        Element firstIdElement = (Element) idList.item(0);
                        NodeList textIdList = firstIdElement.getChildNodes();
                        // --id
                        map.put(KEY_ID, textIdList.item(0).getNodeValue()
                                .trim());

                        // 2.-------
                        NodeList nameList = firstAircraftElement
                                .getElementsByTagName(KEY_NAME);
                        Element firstNameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                        NodeList textNameList = firstNameElement
                                .getChildNodes();
                        // --name
                        map.put(KEY_NAME, textNameList.item(0).getNodeValue()
                                .trim());

                        // 3.-------
                        NodeList iconList = firstAircraftElement
                                .getElementsByTagName(KEY_ICON);
                        Element firstIconElement = (Element) iconList.item(0);
                        NodeList textIconList = firstIconElement
                                .getChildNodes();
                        // -- Image Icon
                        map.put(KEY_ICON, textIconList.item(0).getNodeValue()
                                .trim());
                        // Add to the Arraylist
                        actorDataCollection.add(map);

                }
            }

            BinderActorData bindingData = new BinderActorData(this,
                    actorDataCollection);
            // Adding items to listview
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            // Adding items to listview
            inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

            list.setAdapter(bindingData);

            /**
             * Enabling Search Filter
             * */
            inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    //BrowseActors.this.bindingData.getFilter().filter(cs);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });

            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(BrowseActors.this, ViewActor.class);

                    // parameters
                    i.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position + 1));

                    /*
                     * selected item parameters 
                     */

                    i.putExtra("name",
                            actorDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_NAME));
                    i.putExtra("icon",
                            actorDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON));

                    // start the sample activity
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }

        catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", "Loading exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search will be implemented on original data source, it could be XML/JSON/database or anything else.

You're using "position" parameter for search, I think you can use the View view parameter.
Just keep a hidden field in the ListView row, and map it with some sort of primary key.

When OnClick event occurs, you can then get the row layout from view and do a findViewByID() call to get your hidden control. From the value of that control, you can call a back-end web service or run an x-path query or anything you want.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me an example about it.